# Dynamic metadata in Blade component

Tags: vuejs2, laravel-blade, metadata

I want to create dynamic metadata based on VueJS 2 data input. I know, i cannot do it dynamically with Vue (because metadata are out of #app container) and also cannot use php ofc.

I have for example this in my blade file

```
@section('head')
    <title>{variable content}</title>
    <meta name="description" content="{variable content}">
    <meta property="og:title" content="{variable content}"/>
@endsection
```

and my content looks like this:

```
@section('content')
    <main class="main-content">
        <section class="open-positions-detail">
            <open-positions-detail>
                {{ csrf_field() }}
            </open-positions-detail>
        </section>
    </main>
@endsection
```

In `open-position-detail` component is all vue logic and from there I want to get info for metadata.

Any idea, how to do that?

Comment: `I know, i cannot do it dynamically with Vue`.  That's not true.  Here is a [vue 2](https://vue-meta.nuxtjs.org/) library to do so.  There are others out there as well.